# Windows Server IIS 2003 FTP connection lost

Tags: ftp, iis

Some files are transferred to an FTP service on a 2003 windows server machine. Regularly, those files are incomplete or corrupt. The supplier blaims the FTP connection which is closed, suspecting the server is full. However it isn't.

Looking at the log I see the connection and a 226 status. I've read this means transfer is finished successfully. Am I right? 
Are there any other methods to view whether a transaction was interrupted?
If indeed the connection was lost, which possibilities do I have to troubleshoot and solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any quotas configured for connections/users/sites?

Comment: Time-out was set at 120s. Connections limited to 100.000. Have not seen a user limitation, but acces is denied from all, except 4 listed ip's. Since the transaction has succeeded earlier, I assume the latter cannot be an issue

Comment: Test the timeout and return the results.

Comment: How to test? Files from other suppliers (one being 850mb, while the file with issues is only 190mb) have been uploaded successfully. Then, if the connection is timed-out, should the log not list a status other than 226?

Comment: True, and the status code seems to suggest completion ("Closing data connection. Requested file action successful (for example, file transfer or file abort)."), however this may not mean that the file cotnents are verified, just that the action ahs completed. Does Event Viewer suggest anything? Do you have the correct MIME types configured in IIS?

Comment: Have not seen any related issues in the Event Viewer. Not sure which MIME types would be correct.